# Store prime factor by 2-d array for one number

Tags: java, arrays, prime-factoring

I'm writing a method to store a number's prime factor.
I'm asked to use 2-d array to store its prime factor and the factor's number.

```
public static int[][] getMatrix (long x){
        int[][] matrix =new int[10][2];
        int count;
        for (int i = 2, j = 0; i <=x / 2; i++) {
           count=0;
           while (x % i == 0) {
               x = x/i;
               count++;
           }
           matrix[j][0] = i;

           matrix[j][1] = count;
           j++;
       }
       return matrix;
   }
```

But this code only store data into the first row of the array.
Could someone help me correct it or privide other ideas?
if I use the following code to output the result.

```
for(int row=0;row<b_matrix.length;row++)
        {
            for(int column=0;column<2;column++)
            {
                System.out.print(b_matrix[row][column]+" ");
            }
        }
```

And x=9 I got this:

```
2 0 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

x=6 I got this:

```
2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

such as :6

```
matrix[0][0]=2  matrix[0][1]=1
matrix[1][0]=3  matrix[1][1]=1 //can't store
```

such as :9

```
matrix[0][0]=2   matrix[0][1]=0//only output the next row when this equals to 0 
matrix[1][0]=3   matrix[1][1]=2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is right except, in the for loop `i` should go till `x` instead of `x/2` as follows,

```
for (int i = 2, j = 0; i <= x; i++)
```

Output for `getMatrix(60)`:

```
2   2   
3   1   
4   0   
5   1   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0
```

Comment: oh, I got it, the value of x is changed in the method because of `x= x/i;` , there is no need to be divided by 2, thank you very much.